# Problem - Sum of digits

Tags: recreational-mathematics

For every numbers with $3$ digits you calculate the product of the numbers. After that you take the sum of the products, what number do you get?

I didn't know how to do this exactly. What would be the easiest way?

Comment: Sum of which products? You only mentioned one product.

Comment: Do you mean that for every 3-digit number, take the product of the digits, and sum the results over all 3-digit number?

Comment: @ShuXiaoLi Yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you do this for 1-digit numbers, then the answer is $0+1+2+...+9=45$.

Suppose you do this for 2-digit numbers, then the answer is
\begin{align}
 & 0\cdot 0 + 0\cdot1+\cdots+0\cdot9 + \\
 & 1\cdot 0 + 1\cdot1+\cdots+1\cdot9 + \\
 & \quad\cdots\quad\cdots\quad\cdots\quad\cdots \\
 & 9\cdot0 + 9\cdot1+\cdots+9\cdot9
\end{align}
which factors as $(0+1+\cdots+9)^2$.

Suppose you do this for 3-digit numbers, then the answer will analogously factor as $(0+1+\cdots+9)^3$.

In general, for $k$-digit numbers, the answer is $45^k$.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of n1*n2*n3 with 0 <= n1,n2,n3 <= 9
= (Sum of n1 with 0 <= n1 <= 9) * (Sum of n2 with 0 <= n2 <= 9) * (Sum of n3 with 0 <= n3 <= 9)
= (Sum of n with 0 <= n <= 9)^3
= (9*10/2)^3
= 45^3
= 91125

Comment: Note that numbers with a digit zero do not contribute to the sum.  It doesn't hurt to have them in, however.

Answer (score 1):

Your sum factorises to $(1+2+\ldots+9)(1+2+\ldots+9)(1+2+\ldots+9)=45^{3}$.
To see this, expand term by term.